# How to rotate vector by quaternion in python

Tags: ros, quaternion, learning-tf, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What is the python tf API to rotate a vector by a quaternion to get another vector?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/196149/how-to-rotate-vector-by-quaternion-in-python/) by [robzz](https://answers.ros.org/users/3420/robzz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 328 on 2014-10-28

Post score: 9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Okay, based on @tfoote's response and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4870905/346814) to a related question, I *think* this does the job:

```
# rotate vector v1 by quaternion q1 
def qv_mult(q1, v1):
    # comment this out if v1 doesn't need to be a unit vector
    v1 = tf.transformations.unit_vector(v1)
    q2 = list(v1)
    q2.append(0.0)
    return tf.transformations.quaternion_multiply(
        tf.transformations.quaternion_multiply(q1, q2), 
        tf.transformations.quaternion_conjugate(q1)
    )[:3]
```

---

Originally posted by [robzz](https://answers.ros.org/users/3420/robzz/) with karma: 328 on 2014-10-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 11

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vik748](https://answers.ros.org/users/29926/vik748/) on 2018-07-12**:
After a lot of searching, this is what I needed.  A comment, the unit_vector conversion might not make sense depending on the application.  If you are transforming velocities, you might not want to do the conversion.

**Comment by [JadTawil](https://answers.ros.org/users/29121/jadtawil/) on 2018-10-21**:
Can you please explain the math being done here? Also vik748 can you elaborate?

**Comment by [mojovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/31260/mojovski/) on 2018-11-02**:
and there is no more complicated way?

**Comment by [Enmar](https://answers.ros.org/users/41029/enmar/) on 2019-09-30**:
This is what i needed!
I just multiplied this resulting vector by my vector length to get the transformation!

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2021-11-11**:
This answer is concise, matches the code above: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/28395/rotating-vector3-by-a-quaternion

> Pre-multiply the vector with q and post-multiply it with the conjugate q*

**Comment by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) on 2021-11-11**:
We're assuming this is a 3-long vector, right?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's a copy of transformations.py embedded inside tf for linear math operations.

https://github.com/ros/geometry/blob/indigo-devel/tf/src/tf/transformations.py

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-10-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [robzz](https://answers.ros.org/users/3420/robzz/) on 2014-10-28**:
Right, so which of those transformation rotates a vector by a quaternion, if any?

**Comment by [robzz](https://answers.ros.org/users/3420/robzz/) on 2014-10-28**:
Do I need to do matrix multiplications outside of those functions to accomplish this? If so, which? Better yet: where can I find examples of doing this? I've been search online for such an example using python tf, but with no luck.

**Comment by [Rick Armstrong](https://answers.ros.org/users/13391/rick-armstrong/) on 2014-10-28**:
Hi robzz,
Have a closer look at the link that tfoote posted; the comments give an explanation and examples.

**Comment by [robzz](https://answers.ros.org/users/3420/robzz/) on 2014-10-28**:
@RickArmstrong Hm I don't see any comments about rotating a vector by a quaternion there. I posted an answer here with some code that seems to work for the few cases that I've tried, using some of those functions. Would you mind taking a look?

**Comment by [robzz](https://answers.ros.org/users/3420/robzz/) on 2014-10-28**:
Or, point me to the location in that 1700 line file that you're referring to :)

**Comment by [Rick Armstrong](https://answers.ros.org/users/13391/rick-armstrong/) on 2014-10-29**:
Yep, that's the ticket. Have a look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation) to get an idea of /why/ this works.